# Manually correlating OpenTelemetry traces from separate processes

Tags: c#, open-telemetry

Suppose I have 2 console apps (*App1* and *App2*) that generate traces using `System.Diagnostics.Activity`. *App1* will trigger *App2* but not via HTTP requests so there are no request headers for me to use.

When I view the traces in Jaeger, I see 2 services (*App1* and *App2*) and 2 separate traces *App1:Step1* and *App2:Step2*. The trace for *App2:Step2* contains a warning `invalid parent span IDs=...; skipping clock skew adjustment`

This is my **App1.csproj** and **App2.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Exporter.OpenTelemetryProtocol" Version="1.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**App1\Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using OpenTelemetry;
using OpenTelemetry.Exporter;
using OpenTelemetry.Resources;
using OpenTelemetry.Trace;

namespace App1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TracerProvider? tracer = Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
                .ConfigureResource(builder =>
                {
                    builder.AddService(nameof(App1));
                })
                .AddSource(nameof(App1))
                .AddOtlpExporter(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.Endpoint = new Uri("http://localhost:14317"); // Jaeger container
                    cfg.Protocol = OtlpExportProtocol.Grpc;
                })
                .Build();

            ActivitySource source = new ActivitySource(nameof(App1));
            using (Activity? activity = source.StartActivity("Step1"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(App1)} activity ID: {activity?.Id}");
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); // fake work
            }

            tracer?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**App2\Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using OpenTelemetry;
using OpenTelemetry.Exporter;
using OpenTelemetry.Resources;
using OpenTelemetry.Trace;

namespace App2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TracerProvider? tracer = Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
                .ConfigureResource(builder =>
                {
                    builder.AddService(nameof(App2));
                })
                .AddSource(nameof(App2))
                .AddOtlpExporter(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.Endpoint = new Uri("http://localhost:14317"); // Jaeger container
                    cfg.Protocol = OtlpExportProtocol.Grpc;
                })
                .Build();

            ActivitySource source = new ActivitySource(nameof(App2));
            using (Activity? activity = source.StartActivity("Step2"))
            {
                string parentId = "..."; // set to App1's activity.Id
                activity?.SetParentId(parentId);
                Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(App2)} activity ID: {activity?.Id}");
                Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(App2)} activity parent ID: {activity?.ParentId}");
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); // fake work
            }

            tracer?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

What do I need to set on the activities so that Jaeger shows a single trace containing both App1 and App2?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out. In *App2*, instead of starting an activity and then setting the activity's parent ID via `activity?.SetParentId(...)` , the correct way is to start the activity with the trace parent ID and trace state.

```
string? traceParent = "..."; // set to App1's activity.Id
string? traceState = "..."; // set to App1's activity.TraceStateString
using (Activity? activity = source.StartActivity("Step2", traceParent, traceState))
{
    // do work
}
```